# Further smooth the vertices of THREE.TextGeometry object via threex.dilategeometry.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertices

This is quite a specific question so I will do my best to articulate and explain the problem. So my goal is to create an effect that makes my TextGeometry look dilated or *Bloated Text*. I managed to find a Three.js extension called [threex.dilategeometry.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.geometricglow/blob/master/threex.dilategeometry.js) will allows me to dilate the geometry of the object.

1. For example this is how my text normally looks:

[image: Normal TextGeometry]

2. With the inclusion of the threex.dilategeometry I apply a dilate factor of %15 so the text now looks like this:

[image: threex.dilategeometry effect]

So has you can see the effect works as expected. Please take a look at the code for this below:

```
    //Self made function to create text

    var one = new threeLab.asset.CreateMasterText(this.text,'Lambert');
    this.scene.add(one.wireframe);
    this.scene.add(one.mesh);

    //lets clone it
    var geoclone = one.geometry.clone();

    //need these to make it work
    geoclone.mergeVertices();
    //geoclone.computeCentroids();
    geoclone.computeFaceNormals();
    geoclone.computeVertexNormals();

    //the threex dilate effect
    THREEx.dilateGeometry(geoclone, 0.15);

    //create new material and add to a new mesh to create the halo effect
    var testMat     = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({color:0x222222});
    var meshHalo    = new THREE.Mesh(geoclone, testMat );

    this.scene.add( meshHalo );
```

In order for the extension to work it is reliant on:

```
    geoclone.mergeVertices();
    geoclone.computeFaceNormals();
    geoclone.computeVertexNormals();
```

Which I assume does all the vertices/face calculations to translate them with the dilate effect. One thing that I have noticed as a result of the effect with TextGeometry is that there are parts of the letters which have not translated well and you will see jagged edges on some of the letters:

[image]
[image]

So my question being, is it possible to somehow smooth further the vertices of the Text geometry to give a more smooth and less jagged appearance?

**UPDATE 30/03/17**

So I increased the bevel-segments of my extruded text geometry which helped to round it off better before I applied the threex effect

[image: bevelsegments increase]

[image: bevelsegments2]

Comment: You can get dilated / bloated looking text with the TextGeometry bevel settings. take a look [HERE](https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/geometry-browser.html#TextGeometry), turning on the 'bevelEnabled' and playing with the bevel settings. Just using those will probably work better.

Comment: Thank you @2pha for giving a different perspective on achieving the same effect, as you can see the increase bevel-segment has kept the text more round and smooth. many many tnxs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I increased the 'Bevelsegments' of the TextGeometry object to create a more rounder text. The whole purpose of the exercise is that I wanted to encase text with the object like below:

[image]

[image]

Many thanks @2pha :)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this effect with a complex (loaded) mesh?